# Twitter-bootstrap fixed layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a twitter-bootstrap layout, that has fixed side bar and content.

However, when width of browser window is reduced, content goes under sidebar.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CaYSt/

Comment: What browser are you using? The content does not go under the sidebar in either Chrome or Firefox when I view this code.

Comment: I have tried with Safari, Opera, FF. Please check the screenshot.
http://i49.tinypic.com/348fy8x.png

Comment: Well I can't replicate it in Chrome or Firefox, so it's hard to say. I would try removing the `float: left;` on the `span2` and `span10` divs and see if that helps. I'm not quite sure why that float is there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The responsive layout is responsible for most disposition shifting resulting from window resizing. It is activated by default in the [examples provided by the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples).

You can disable the responsiveness of the layout by **not** including `bootstrap-responsive.css` as seen [in the docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

Note : the fluid grid has nothing to do with responsiveness. Both can be used independently.

Comment: I have already removed bootstrap-responsive.css and I dont want to use fluid grid. Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/CaYSt/ and there is the screenshot http://i49.tinypic.com/348fy8x.png